# Conv Autoencoder layer progression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I am tying to set up a simple convolutional autoencoder:

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

input (InputLayer)           (None, 64, 64, 1)         0

---

encoder_conv_1 (Conv2D)      (None, 64, 64, 32)        320

---

max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 32, 32, 32)        0

---

decoder_conv_1 (Conv2D)      (None, 30, 30, 32)        9248

---

up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 60, 60, 32)        0

---

## output (Conv2D)              (None, 60, 60, 1)         289

Why isn't my last layer going back to 64, 64 ,1? Or rather why is the decoder_conv_1 layer going to 30, 30 ,32 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss padding same. try in this way...

```
inp = Input((64,64,1))
c = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inp)
c = MaxPool2D()(c)
c = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(c) # <=== padding same
c = UpSampling2D()(c)
out = Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same')(c)

m = Model(inp, out)
m.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, 64, 64, 1)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2 (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 1)         289       
=================================================================
```

Comment: This solved it. Not sure why I had the padding property missing on the last layer. Thank you.